# NotificationManager in BlackBerry 10 (Android Runtime)

Tags: android-notifications, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

My App uses AlarmManager along with NotificationManager to post Notifications when the app is in the background or closed. In PlayBook simulator it pops up a message containing the custom icon and message configured in the Notification object. When I open the app by clicking on the notification I receive an Intent (calling getIntent on onCreate if the app is closed, or onNewIntent() if the activity is already running) with information I can use to perform an action. However on BlackBerry 10 simulator all that happens is the App's icon get a little badge, without any information, and nothing is passed along to the app when opened. Is this the intended behavior? The user is left wondering what triggered the notification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported Intents on BlackBerry Android Runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823295/unsupported-intents-on-blackberry-android-runtime)

Comment: What does Notifications have to do with Intents ? Its not a duplicate.

Comment: You spawned 2 questions that are essentially the same in a 4 minutes interval. I've flagged this since the other one is more elaborated. You might want to merge them in one single question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really think you didn't read them properly. This one is the inability of the BB10 Simulator to show Notifications posted with NotificationManager. The other is about starting activities with common data sharing/acquiring Intents. I really can't see them as essentially the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from BlackBerry team regarding this issue, this is still not supported on the Simulator:

"For BlackBerry 10 the user would see their notifications in the BlackBerry Hub area. So they would be able to take action on the notification or delete it etc. Unfortunately you won't be able to see that just yet within the simulator. But if you are seeing the notification splat on the app icon, the notification would show in the BlackBerry Hub correctly."

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/NotificationManager-BB10/td-p/2030007